# Google sheets Array split function formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this Google sheet:

I am using this formula to split my strings in columns

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(D2:D=1, SPLIT(A2:A, "+"), SPLIT(C2:C, "+"))))


 Molecules                               ID  NAME                           Vitamin_in_name     NAME1            NAME2         NAME3
 VITAMIN B1 + VITAMIN B6 + VITAMIN B12    1  VITAMIN B1,B6,B12                       1         VITAMIN B1       VITAMIN B6    VITAMIN B12
                                          2  LIDOCAINE + VITAMIN B4,B8,B10           1         
                                          3  SALICYLIC ACID + TALC                   0         SALICYLIC ACID   TALC
```

I would like to return this sheet. IF the word "vitamin_in_name" = 1 and "molecules" row is empty to re-format the data like in ID2 Column name1, name2, name3. how can i do modify my array formula to do that?

```
 Molecules                               ID  NAME                           Vitamin_in_name     NAME1            NAME2         NAME3         NAME4
 VITAMIN B1 + VITAMIN B6 + VITAMIN B12    1  VITAMIN B1,B6,B12                       1         VITAMIN B1       VITAMIN B6    VITAMIN B12
                                          2  LIDOCAINE + VITAMIN B4,B8,B10           1         LIDOCAINE        VITAMIN B4       VITAMIN B8    VITAMIN B10
                                          3  SALICYLIC ACID + TALC                   0         SALICYLIC ACID   TALC
```

Comment: Could you please share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15ZU_mUrnTvhssgHF231dHKFjjsD7t_0pEFm0ysKoL6A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @lamblichious So i would like to return in the second row :  LIDOCAINE        VITAMIN B4       VITAMIN B8    VITAMIN B10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a bit ambiguous, since you didn't specify what should happen if both these conditions are true:

- `Molecules` column is not blank.
- `Vitamin_in_name` is not 1.

I assumed that, in this case, the values should come from column C, and so `Vitamin_in_name` is not really needed for this.

In any case, I would do the following:

- Check if column A is blank with [ISBLANK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290).
- If column A is blank then (1) use [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245) to replace all `,` from column C with `+VITAMIN`, and (2) [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136) using `+` as separator.
- If column A is not blank, use a simple `SPLIT` on column A, with `+` as separator.

The resulting formula could be this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(C2:C,",","+VITAMIN "),"+"),SPLIT(A2:A,"+"))))
```

[image]